# Jquery Move Table Row but NOT past header

Tags: jquery, sorting, row, move

I have table rows that move up and down, but my problem is that the data table rows replace the table header (first row).

I want a fixed first row so that when you click the Up arrow you do not move the row up to replace the header.

I have tried some conditional logic to check if the current row is the table's first row, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

<!--- Move: click to move rows up or down --->
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");

<!-- this var does not work -->
var firstrow = $('table')[0].rows[0]; 

<!-- Check that is not the first row NEEDS FIXED -->
if (row != firstrow){

if ($(this).is(".up")) {
row.insertBefore(row.prev());
} else {
row.insertAfter(row.next());
}
}
});
});

<table>
<tr>
<td>Do Not Replace Me</td>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Two</td>
<td>
<a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
<a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Three</td>
<td>
<a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
<a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table must stay as is, and I cannot change td to th or anything like that.

I am hoping there is just a way to fix those two lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would, as I suppose you know (given your disclaimer that the html must 'stay as is...'), be much easier if you could put the header/first row into a `thead` element and the remainder into a `tbody`, but one way that works with the html 'as is:'

```
$(".up,.down").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");

    var firstrow = $('table tr:first');

    if ($(this).is(".up") && row.prevAll().length > 1) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    }
    else if ($(this).is(".down") && row.nextAll().length > 0) {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LqBTV/).

Incidentally, and as an aside, your script may have been generating errors from the comment (though I do suspect the were added for our benefit, rather than in your actual JavaScript) syntax:

```
<!-- comment text -->
```

is html syntax, and within the confines of the `<script></script>` tags is invalid, to comment JavaScript use either:

```
// single-line comment
// which needs to have the double-slash
// preface each comment-line...
```

or:

```
/* This is a multi-line
   comment, and this text
   will happily remain commented-out
   until you get to
   one of these comment-close things, just to the right -> */
```

References:

- [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length).

Comment: Yes it would be easier with a thead, but that was the problem. Yes the comments were just an example. Wasn't sure how the code block would display them. 1st post at Stackoverflow. Thanks anyways for your thoughtfulness and thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `index` function should be some help here.

```
$(".up, .down").click(function() {
    // get parent tr
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    var $link = $(this);
    // count all tr
    var count = $('table tr').length;
    // if tr isn't the first
    if($row.index() !== 0) {
        // if direction is up and there is a tr above
        if($link.hasClass('up') && $row.index() > 1) {
            $row.insertBefore($row.prev());
        } 
        // if direction is down and there is a tr below
        else if($link.hasClass('down') && $row.index() < count - 1) {
            $row.insertAfter($row.next());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue where my rows were moving above the 'header' rows in my table.

I solved it using a basic class call in the jquery and assigning the class to the table. This just adds another level of depth to the element specification so it ignores table rows that do not comply.

Try this:

var row = $(this).parents("tr.**MoveableRow**:first");

Then add to each  tag, class = "MoveableRow".

Ex: `<tr class="MoveableRow">`